# Прогнозируемый временной ряд с Sarima в python3 с сезонной переодичностью в неделю

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо на основе текущих данных спрогнозировать будущие данные.
Нашел подробный и интересный [гайд на питоне](https://www.linuxspace.org/archives/18256)
Проблема в том, что есть параметр `s` который определяет сезонную периодичность.

> Термин s является периодичностью временного ряда (4 для квартальных периодов, 12 для годовых периодов и т. Д.).

У меня недельная периодичность, поэтому `s=7`.

Однако если посмотреть на скриншот, где начиная с `2017-04-24` прогнозируемые скриптом данные, видно что прогноз очень странный и не учитывает сезонную периодичность.
[image: скрин из консоли]
Вопрос. Что я делаю не так?

Нашел в чем была проблема. Я искал только минимальное положительное значение `aic`, а надо было любое минимальное.
Вот рабочий вариант:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import itertools
import warnings
import sys
import pandas as pd
values = [float(s) for s in sys.argv[1].split(',')]
dates = sys.argv[2].split(',')
y = pd.Series(values, index=dates)
p = d = q = range(0, 2)
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 7) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
config = []
for param in pdq:
  for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
    try:
      mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                      order=param,
                                      seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                      enforce_stationarity=False,
                                      enforce_invertibility=False)
      results = mod.fit(disp=0)
      if not np.isnan(results.aic):
        config.append({ 'param': param, 'param_seasonal': param_seasonal, 'aic': results.aic })
    except:
      continue
min_config = min(config, key=lambda x: x['aic'])
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                order=min_config['param'],
                                seasonal_order=min_config['param_seasonal'],
                                enforce_stationarity = False,
                                enforce_invertibility = False)
results = mod.fit(disp=0)
pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=7)
y_forecasted = pred_uc.predicted_mean
# print(y)
print(y_forecasted.to_json(date_format='iso'))
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, пожалуйста

Comment: @KitScribe выложил код, правда за ночь я сам понял и исправил ошибку. Так что там уже рабочий код